# How to use the backgrounder SpringBoardHooks?

Tags: iphone, background, jailbreak, multitasking

I would love to use [these hooks](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-backgrounder/source/browse/trunk/Extension/SpringBoardHooks.h) for a jailbreak iPhone app. This would allow the app to request to be backgrounded, providing that Backgrounder is installed. Seeing previous questions on StackOverflow, I think I'm not the only one who could use this.

What are the steps required? Do I need to extract the private SpringBoard api's, or do I even need to follow [procedures](http://www.ipodtouchfans.com/forums/showthread.php?t=163185) for compiling MobileSubstrate pluginss?

I would prefer creating a minimal header file that allows me to send this message to Backgrounder, but I have basically no idea how to go about this. Suggestions are very welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Backgrounder uses MobileSubstrate to hook some functions on SprindBoard and UIApplication, the problem with iOS 4.2 (I don't have a 4.1 version to try it) is that you can ignore the applicationSuspend event but after 10 secs springboard will kill your application.
I've been looking for the same thing you're asking and until now I know:
- I can use MobileSubstrate to hook SpringBoard's functions like Backgrounder does
OR
- There must be a way to tell Springboard your app is like Safari or it's being debugged.

I just need to find that thing that makes MobileSafari different. But if you want try using MobileSubstrate, you can check backgrounder on github and:

http://modmyi.com/forums/iphone-ipod-touch-sdk-development-discussion/728944-tutorial-how-compile-mobile-substrate-extension-xcode.html